# how to create a crossword style grid / large number of divs or other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

so I need to have a grid on screen in a web browser / mobile devices that each grid item holds 1 letter.

A bit like a crossword puzzle, but using most of the screen Doing it using div's seems to be to hard as the performance isn't great to support creating a screen full of 1000's of divs as you can fit a lot of text on screen so a lot of divs.

Any suggestions as a way to achieve this text / grid layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use HTML 5 Canvas this will maybe help you:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/wordico/

Answer (score 1):

`<table>`

Seems obvious but yeah.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is an impractical, but still proper use of a table, so I'd have to agree with you.

Comment: I only answered it with such an obtuse answer as the OP first thought of divs - so comptability might be an issue?

Comment: Even still, it could be construed as a legitimate reason (in a semantic sense) to use tables.

Answer (score 0):

I like this as a [grid creator](http://grids.heroku.com/). You would still have to create the vertical height. Probably with some class.

Comment: Thanks but not quiet what I was after